# Using non-trivial objects in RLink

Tags: interoperability, rlink

I would like to use RLink to access [igraph](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/), which has an R interface.  I do not know R; my motivation for learning it is to be able to access igraph easily.  I installed igraph using `install.packages("igraph")`.  This seems to have worked fine (I'm doing this on Windows, [where package installation is supported](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15386/12)).  I can load the package using `REvaluate["library(igraph)"]`

Now I would like to reference some igraph functions and use them, in analogy to this:

```
sin = RFunction["sin"]
cos = RFunction["cos"]
sin@cos[1]
```

I did

```
fullgraph = RFunction["graph.full"]
diameter = RFunction["diameter"]
```

I created a graph using `g = fullgraph[5]` and I tried `diameter[g]`.  The value it returns is `{0.}`.  This is not the same what I get using `REvaluate["diameter(graph.full(5))"]`, which returns `{1.}`.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Does RLink support the kinds of objects returned by igraph, or does it only support basic built-in types?  Another thing I observed is that if I try these commands several times, then `sin@cos[1]` (with the above definitions) will stop working too in the sense that it will throw error about being unable to set variables (RLink's internal state probably becomes inconsistent), but I can't reproduce this consistently.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### The problem

The full answer would require venturing into quite sophisticated matters, and also some of them are not yet fully clear to me. What I can tell right now that your use case hits the borderline between what can be fully imported into RLink (in the sense that it can then be equivalently exported back), and what *appears* to be imported correctly but in practice can only be used on the Mathematica side, while reverse import into R does not result into a correct object on the R side.

#### General situation with data types in RLink

Generally, RLink supports most of R objects, not just the basic data types. The reason it is able to do that is that R has a simple and consistent object model, so that the non-core types are usually represented by the core types with certain attributes. For example, a *factor* data type is actually an integer vector with additional attributes `levels` and `class`, and *data frame* is actually a list with `class` attribute set to `data.frame`, and a number of other attributes. A more detailed discussion of the subset of R's object model supported by RLink can be found in the [tutorial on R data types in RLink](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/RLink/tutorial/DataTypes.html).

The types explicitly not supported include environments, certain language constructs (type *language*), S4 classes, and a few other types. Still, the set of supported types is large enough for RLink to be able to import even quite complex R objects, such as e.g. results of liner model fit (`lm`) and nonlinear model fit (`nlm`) commands. However, it would be fair to say that currently RLink is biased towards importing things into Mathematica rather than exporting from Mathematica to R. Objects that are imported into Mathematica may contain parts which generally will not export correctly back to R.

Most of such non-exportable objects are represented on Mathematica side by RLink's heads [`RCode`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/RLink/ref/RCode.html) and [`REnvironment`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/RLink/ref/REnvironment.html), but apparently your case falls under the same category (being, however, undetected by RLink). Since such reverse imports are needed if we want to call RLink's function references on Mathematica arguments, we do have a problem for such non-exportable types.

#### The case at hand

An attempt to import an `igraph` object from R into Mathematica results into a deceivingly simple expression:

```
REvaluate["graph.full(5)"]
```

> ```
>  RObject[{{{2., 3., 4., 5.}}, {{1., 3., 4., 5.}}, {{1., 2., 4., 5.}}, 
>     {{1., 2., 3., 5.}}, {{1., 2., 3., 4.}}, {Null}, {Null}, {Null}, {Null}}, 
>     RAttributes["class" :> {"igraph"}]]
> ```

however, sending this back to R does not reconstruct correctly the full `igraph` object (there are a number of technical details I am leaving out at the moment, such as the role of `RList`/ `RVector` interpretation ambiguity, and a few other things, but the long story short is that even when one does account for all that correctly, the R object is not exported from Mathematica properly).

### Possible solutions

While I will dig deeper into the exact reasons for this behavior and expand this post when I get those, right now I can suggest a few possible workarounds, which hopefully will help you to get the job done.

#### A work-around based on `parse`, `deparse` and `eval`

First let us discuss a workaround based on R's functions `parse`, `deparse` and `eval` (more or less analogous to Mathematica's `ToExpression`, `ToString` and `Evaluate`). Define the following functions:

```
eval = RFunction["function(code){eval(parse(text=code))}"]

apply = 
     RFunction["function(fun,deparsedCode){
                    fun(eval(parse(text = deparsedCode)))
                }"
     ]
```

There will be certain inconvenience since you will have to use `deparse`:

```
fgr = REvaluate["deparse(graph.full(5))"];
```

( I left out the output but it is a list of strings, which you can, if you wish, join together by using `StringJoin`).

To obtain the same result as before, you can use

```
eval[fgr]
```

> ```
>  RObject[{{{2., 3., 4., 5.}}, {{1., 3., 4., 5.}}, {{1., 2., 4., 5.}}, 
>     {{1., 2., 3., 5.}}, {{1., 2., 3., 4.}}, {Null}, {Null}, {Null}, {Null}}, 
>     RAttributes["class" :> {"igraph"}]]
> ```

but now, calling your `diameter` will give the correct result:

```
apply[diameter, fgr]

(* {1.} *)
```

#### A better way: using R's closures to emulate object references in RLink

The above workaround has a few flaws characteristic to solutions using parsing (for example, `ToString`-`ToExpression` cycles in Mathematica). First, we are in general not guaranteed that this procedure will be robust for all inputs. Second, for large graphs this may seriously impact performance.

Of course, what your example did reveal is the need for object references (handles) for RLink, both for more complex types and for core types as well (that would be analogous to `ReturnAsJavaObject` in J/Link). While RLink does not "natively" support such a mechanism, it does support R closures, and here I will show how one can use them to emulate object references.

Define the following functions:

```
REvaluate["makeObjectRef <- function(obj){function(){obj}}"];

applyToRef = RFunction["function(fun,ref){makeObjectRef(fun(ref()))}"];

deref = RFunction["function(ref){ref()}"];
```

The function `makeObjectRef` you should use on the R side to wrap it around any value which you want to convert to a reference. What it does is to return a closure which would return that value when called with zero arguments. The functions `applyToRef` and `deref` are to be used on the Mathematica side. The former would take a function to apply, and a reference (the closure produced by `makeObjectReference`), and return a reference to the resulting object. The latter (`deref`) will "dereference" any reference created via `makeObjectRef`, and return the value of the R object.

Here is how we can use this. First, define a reference:

```
graphRef = REvaluate["makeObjectRef(graph.full(5))"];
```

Check:

```
deref[graphRef]
```

> ```
>  RObject[{{{2., 3., 4., 5.}}, {{1., 3., 4., 5.}}, {{1., 2., 4., 5.}}, 
>     {{1., 2., 3., 5.}}, {{1., 2., 3., 4.}}, {Null}, {Null}, {Null}, {Null}}, 
>     RAttributes["class" :> {"igraph"}]]
> ```

Now, the result we look for:

```
deref[applyToRef [diameter, graphRef]]

(* {1.} *)
```

### Remarks

Of the two workarounds I suggested, I would personally prefer the second one, based on the emulation of R object references using R closures. The emulation is good enough, and should not result in a serious overhead. The only serious problem is that the current function reference mechanism does not provide a function to release a function reference which is no longer needed (which is certainly a shortcoming. I could show a hack which would do that but it is implementation-dependent). So, one should be careful to not create too many references since they will hog the memory.

Your example certainly reveals a number of shortcomings currently present in RLink. I hope to have those addressed reasonably soon.

Comment: I'm becoming more and more convinced that for the type of use that I showed in the question, working with handles is much better than transferring all of the data.  I was playing with another package, and I can round-trip compete objects between R and Mathematica.   But doing it is awfully slow and I can't do much with the object in Mathematica other than pass them back to R anyway:  they're too complex to disassemble in Mma.  You're on the right track with the idea of using handles.  J/Link does this too.

Comment: @Szabolcs I used to have handles in the other link I worked on before, but not for RLink. Partly this was because R expressions are immutable, and there is a natural mapping between R and Mathematica in this sense, more so than with Matlab. I do agree that handles are a good thing to have though. The story was that we were not even sure we'd be able to get RLink fully ready for production, and it was actually quite tough to meet the schedule even with the core functionality it currently has. I have a todo list for RLink, with handles (among other things) there, so I hope to get at least ...

Comment: What I meant is that I think you're on the right track with the solution you suggested in this answer, but I don't claim that I have all the practicalities of handles figured out :-) Unfortunately I can't play a lot with RLink yet because I always need to use external packages. I play with it when I can use Windows.  Right now I'm trying to figure out a fast way to conveniently transfer data between an external R installation and Mma (just transfer data, nothing more---save and load.)

Comment: @Szabolcs ... some things on that list done for the next version, but that will only happen if I am given enough time to do that (which is not clear yet). By the way, I did mention already - in case you just need to execute the code but not transfer the object back, use the semicolon at the end of your string of R code. Also, as I mentioned, handles can be rather easily implemented on top of closures (as I described above), and using the type extension mechanism. If I have the time, I will do this some time soon, this should not take long.

Comment: @Szabolcs Are you on Mac OS X?

Comment: Yes, I'm on OS X now.  I sometimes try to run Windows in VirtualBox, but it uses CPU for no reason and has occasional hangs, so it's not ideal.

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, that's a pity that we have this problem for Mac OS X with RLink. One thing you can try is to run Mathematica from a shell script where you set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` so that it includes the directory where dynamic libraries of your R distribution (`libR.dylib` etc) reside. Let me know if that helps. If not, I have another suggestion to complement this one.

Comment: It seems that it works partially.  I couldn't load libraries though and it prints some errors I don't understand: http://pastebin.com/ZYYsEGB8  (`Error in .Call("R_isMethodsDispatchOn", onOff, PACKAGE = "base") : 
  "R_isMethodsDispatchOn" not available for .Call() for package "base"
`)

Comment: @Szabolcs I forgot to mention that you also had to call `InstallR` with the option `"RHomeLocation"` pointing at the root of your external R distro. I think that what happened may have been due to some conflict between the R version coming with RLink and the external one.