# Sending RObject to RFunctions

Tags: rlink

I want to realize function from some R package in Mathematica.
First load RLink and package what I need

```
Needs["RLink`"]
InstallR["RHomeLocation" -> "c:\\R-2.15.3\\"]
REvaluate["library(\"randomForest\")"]
```

then create RObject

```
rf=REvaluate["randomForest(Species~ .,data=iris,importance=TRUE,proximity=TRUE)"];
```

create RFunction that takes an RObject as input

```
treeSize = RFunction["treesize"]
```

Here start a problem. When I call this fuction

```
treeSize[rf]
```

its return following error message

```
RSet::puterr: Error putting the expression ... into a variable myRandomVar123456782845 in R. The last error message issued by R was Error in attr(myRandomVar123456782845[[10]], "dimnames") <- myRandomVar123456751330: 'dimnames' must be a list
```

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22942/12)?

Comment: @Szabolcs Thank. There is answer