# How to plot a 2D region when there are 3 free parameters?

Tags: plotting, regions

How could I obtain the region of payments, with the parameters `a, b, c, d` between 0 and 1 and the sum of all equal to 1?

After the comment/recommendation of belisarius, I edited the original question, and ask you a question in the last line of code.

```
P = {{a, b}, {c, d}}

A = {{2, -1}, {0, 1}}    
B = {{-1, 1}, {2, -1}}

A[[1]].P[[1]] + A[[2]].P[[2]]

f1[a_, b_, c_, d_] = A[[1]].P[[1]] + A[[2]].P[[2]]
f2[a_, b_, c_, d_] = B[[1]].P[[1]] + B[[2]].P[[2]]

ParametricPlot[{f1[a, b, c, d], f2[a, b, c, d]}, {  a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 
  1}, {c, 0, 1}, {d, 0, 1} ]
```

In the last line, how can I code to consider only `a, b, c, d` in $[0,1]$ with $a+b+c+d=1$?

It´s similar to obatining all the convex combinations of the points $(a(i,j),b(i,j))$

Comment: At least for me, it isn't clear what you're trying to do

Comment: @belisarius Yes It´s not very clear! :-)    I want to draw the pairs (f1[a,b,c,d],f2[a,b,c,d]), with a,b,c,d between 0 and 1, and verifyng a+b+c+d=1

Comment: It´s possible that it´s difficult to use Manipulate in this case, because there are 4 parameters (a,b,c,d) interconnected and depending each other.

Answer (score 10):

[Being this the first answer at the site using the `Region` context](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39184/193), I think it deserves an entry on its own:

```
   AppendTo[$ContextPath, "Region`"]
   z = 0; 
   RegionPlot[
         RegionProperty[
                  TransformedRegion[
                        ParametricRegion[{{p1, p2, p4}, 
                                          0 < p1 < 1 && 0 < p2 < 1 - p1 && 0 < p4 < 1 - p1 - p2}], 
                         {2 #1 - #2 + #3, 2 - 3 #1 - #2 - 3 #3} &], 
                   {x, y, z}, ImplicitDescription], 
         {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Beautiful, many thanks! Btw the `ParametricRegion` can be defined in a more straightforward manner using just the problem statement : `ParametricRegion[{{p1,p2,p3,p4},0<p1<1 && 0<p2<1 && 0<p3<1&& 0<p4<1 && p1+p2+p3+p4==1}],{2 #1 - #2 + #4, - #1 + #2 +2 #3 - #4}(...)`.

Answer (score 5):

To start with, I will work in 4 dimensions to accommodate a,b,c,d.

```
P = {a, b, c, d};
M = {{2, -1, 0, 1}, {-1, 1, 2, -1}};
```

The points of your 2D set are the linear transforms, of the form

```
M.P  (* {2 a - b + d, -a + b + 2 c - d} *)
```

where P lies in some 4D set which is defined by $a+b+c+d=1$ and all positive, that is some polytope in 4D. Since you get your 2D points by a linear transform on the 4D points (M.P), and since the linear transform of a polytope is the convex hull of the transform of the extreme points of the polytope, your set will be the convex hull of the points M.P for all P being an extreme point of the 4D polytope.

Not, this 4D polytope is a simple one, you can get its extreme points by all combinations {a,b,c,d} of 0's and 1's that have a sum <= 1. You can generate all the combinations and then `Select` the right ones :

```
Flatten[Table[{a, b, c, d},
  {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}, {c, 0, 1}, {d, 0, 1}], 3]
extremePoints4D = Select[%, Total[#] <= 1 &]

(* {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0}} *)
```

(yes, you could have guessed that just fine!)

Now, transform these to their 2D transforms :

```
Points2D = M.# & /@ extremePoints4D

(* {{0, 0}, {1, -1}, {0, 2}, {-1, 1}, {2, -1}} *)
```

(not all of these will end up extreme points of the 2D region but that's OK, we will take the convex hull and interior points do not matter)
Now, plot the convex hull :

```
<< ComputationalGeometry`
Graphics[Polygon[Points2D[[ConvexHull[Points2D]]]], Frame -> True]
```

[image]

**Note:** This approach needs to generate all extreme points of a polytope; in higher dimensions (4D -> nD) and with constraints not so simple as $a+b+c+d=1$, getting those extreme points gets trickier.

**About the bounding box**

@Silvia got me thinking about the bounding box of the 2D region. With the above method it is quite obvious (min and max x and y over extreme points) but I thought I would suggest another way to do this that has the advantage of working in higher dimensions.

The idea is to get the min and max x and y over all possible (x,y). Linear programming will do just that :

```
(*
Min x (or -x, y, -y)
subject to linear constraints
a + b + c + d = 1
2a - b - d -x = 0
-a + b + 2c - d - y = 0
0 <= a, b, c, d <= 1
-infinity < x, y < infinity

with a 6D vector {a,b,c,d,x,y}.
*)

obj = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1}};
(* obj will be used to min/max y/y *)
M = {{1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {2, -1, 0, 1, -1, 0}, {-1, 1, 2, -1, 0, -1}};
(* M.{a,b,c,d,x,y}=0 generates all 3 constraints *)

bounds = {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}, {-Infinity, Infinity}, {-Infinity, Infinity}}

(* Now get the 4 solutions to min/max x/y: *)
sol = LinearProgramming[#, M, {{1, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}, bounds] & /@ obj
(* and keep the {x,y}'s
sol[[1 ;; 4, 5 ;; 6]]

(* all downhill from here *)

xmin = Min[points[[1 ;; 4, 1]]]
xmax = Max[points[[1 ;; 4, 1]]]
ymin = Min[points[[1 ;; 4, 2]]]
ymax = Max[points[[1 ;; 4, 2]]]
ListPlot[points, AxesOrigin -> {xmin - 1, ymin - 1}, 
 Epilog -> {Orange, Line[{{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}, {xmin, ymax}, {xmin, ymin}}]}]
```

[image: The bounding box]

Comment: Hi A.G., I guess you missed an image by carelessness. I added it back, hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 3):

You have 3 free parameters, since the imposed condition over their sum takes one away.
So, let's plot in 3D the region for those three free parms:

```
RegionPlot3D[(0 < p1 < 1 && 0 < p2 < 1 && 0 < p4 < 1 &&  p1 + p2 + p4 < 1), 
             {p1, 0, 1}, {p2, 0, 1}, {p4, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 30]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Which is equivalent to:

```
Graphics3D[gc = GraphicsComplex[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, 
           Polygon@{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 4}}], 
           Axes -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now your functions `f1` and `f2` can bee written as:

```
f[p_, x_] := Total[p x, 2]
p = {{p1, p2}, {p3, p4}};
a = {{2, -1}, {0, 1}};
b = {{-1, 1}, {2, -1}};
{f[p, a], f[p, b]}
(*
  {2 p1 - p2 + p4, -p1 + p2 + 2 p3 - p4}
*)
```

Which is your target transform.

Now we find a transformation to map any `{p1, p2, p3, p4}` (minus one parm set by the sum restriction) into your target:

```
r = ToRules@
    Reduce[ForAll[{p1, p2, p4}, 
                  TransformationFunction[{{a1, a2, a3, a4}, {b1, b2, b3, b4}, 
                                          {c1, c2, c3, c4}, {d1, d2, d3, d4}}][{p1, p2, p4}] == 
                  {f[p, a], f[p, b], 0} /. p3 -> 1 - p1 - p2 - p4], 
          {a1, a2, a3, a4, b1, b2, b3, b4, c1, c2, c3, c4, d1, d2, d3, d4}];

t = TransformationFunction[{{a1, a2, a3, a4}, {b1, b2, b3, b4}, 
                            {c1, c2, c3, c4}, {d1, d2, d3, d4}}] /. r /. a1 -> 1
```

And now we apply that transformation to our graphics complex:

```
Graphics3D[{FaceForm[Black], EdgeForm[None], 
           GeometricTransformation[gc, t]}, Axes -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And we can show it in 2D as:

```
Graphics[Normal@ GeometricTransformation[gc, t] /. {x_, y_, 0} :> {x, y} /. 
         (VertexNormals -> x_) :> Sequence[], Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Your first `RegionPlot3D` could be simpler: `RegionPlot3D[a + b + c <= 1, {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}, {c, 0, 1}]`

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by [belisarius](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39204/17) and [Simon's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39237/17) [answers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39206/17), I came up with a similar method, but without burdensome `RegionPlot`.

```
Graphics`Region`RegionInit[];

parareg = TransformedRegion[
                ParametricRegion[{
                         {p1, p2, p4},
                         0 < p1 < 1 && 0 < p2 < 1 - p1 && 0 < p4 < 1 - p1 - p2
                         }],
                {2 #1 - #2 + #3, 2 - 3 #1 - #2 - 3 #3} &]

meshreg = MeshRegion@RegionToMeshObject[Evaluate@{
                  {x, y},
                  Prepend[
                   (* Thanks to belisarius, we have a good way to obtain the boundingbox: *)
                          1.1 RegionProperty[parareg, "BoundingBox"],
                          RegionProperty[parareg, {x, y}, "ImplicitDescription"]
                         ]
                }]

GeometryPlot[meshreg, PlotRange -> 1.1 RegionProperty[parareg, "BoundingBox"]]
```

[image: region plot]

Comment: Why doesn't just `GeometryPlot@RegionConvert@parareg` show the result?

Comment: @belisarius It looks like `RegionConvert` will [truncate the object at the boundary of a $2\times 2$ square](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yD1mh.png).

Comment: Yep, `GeometryPlot@
 RegionConvert@
  TransformedRegion[parareg, ScalingTransform[1/10 {1, 1}]]` ... but there must be a way to tell `RegionConvert` to expand the domain

Comment: @belisarius I `Trace`-ed the `RegionConvert` and eventually arrived `RegionToMeshObject`, where the `{{-1,1},{-1,1}}` boundary is just inserted "suddenly". I think more internal trace will be needed for revealing the key point.

Comment: @Silvia I just added the bounding box computation to my response (above).

Comment: @Silvia Try `RegionProperty[parareg, "BoundingBox"]`

Comment: @belisarius That's Nice! I've included your method in my answer :) So are you digging the version in mma 9 or [the up coming one in 10](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/GeometricComputation.html)?

Comment: @Silvia I'm crawling on V9. In fact I have a need to solve this very problem http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6357/193 using Voronoi tessellations. I'm close, but not yet done.

Comment: @belisarius Aha~ That question is in my TODO list too :D But I don't have time for it yet ... Looking forward to your solution :)

Comment: @Silvia I'm delayed because the v9 implementation of the Mesh and Region contexts are buggy. I'm still trying to decide if I'll implement my own or wait till v10. Oh laziness!, mother of us all-

Comment: @belisarius It looks like many of them are documented function in v10 with the same name. I guess even if you write your code in v9, it won't be hard to upgrade to v10.

Answer (score 3):

`Reduce` can be used to turn the system

```
{x == 2 a - b + d, y == -a + b + 2 c - d,
 0 <= a <= 1, 0 <= b <= 1, 0 <= c <= 1, 0 <= d <= 1,
 a + b + c + d == 1}
```

into a system of inequalities of the form (via a [`CylindricalDecomposition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CylindricalDecomposition.html))

```
(x1 < x <= x2 && f1[x] < y < f2[x] && ..) ||
..
```

where the omitted inequalities in the first line constrain the parameters `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` in terms of `x` and `y`.  Only the first pair of each `&&` expression is needed to plot the `{x, y}` region.  From there, the functions `f1` and `f2` form the boundary of the region, so it can be plotted.

The command that will convert the system is basically

```
Reduce[system, {x, y, a, b, c, d}, Reals, Backsubstitution -> True]
```

A key is putting `x` and `y` first.  Then we can extract the `x` and `y` parts with

```
Reduce[system, {x, y, a, b, c, d}, Reals, Backsubstitution -> True][[All, {1, 2}]]
```

Some of the entries will be strict equalities.  These represent boundary points or lines that bound the inequalities and may be removed.  Finally, some of the cases may be combined. `Reduce` initially divides the region according to the `x` coordinates of points of intersection and then it subdivides these.  If we gather the ones with the same `x` inequality (with `Split` below), `Reduce` can then be used to combine them.

Here is this first step:

```
Clear[x, y, a, b, c, d];

P = {{a, b}, {c, d}};
A = {{2, -1}, {0, 1}};
B = {{-1, 1}, {2, -1}};

redSystem = Reduce[{
     {x, y} == Inner[Dot, {Hold @@@ A, Hold @@@ B}, Hold @@@ P, Plus] /. Hold -> List,
     0 <= a <= 1, 0 <= b <= 1, 0 <= c <= 1, 0 <= d <= 1,
     a + b + c + d == 1},
   {x, y, a, b, c, d},
   Reals, 
   Backsubstitution -> True];

removeBoundaries[ineqs_] := Select[ineqs, ! MemberQ[#, _Equal] &];

pieces = removeBoundaries @ redSystem[[All, {1, 2}]];
combinedPieces = Reduce[#, {x, y}, Reals] & /@ Or @@@ SplitBy[List @@ pieces, #[[1, 1]] &]

(* {-1   < x <= 0   && -x < y < 2 + x, 
     0   < x <= 5/7 && -x < y < 1/2 (4 - 3 x), 
     5/7 < x <= 1   && -x < y < 1/2 (4 - 3 x), 
     1    < x < 2   && -1 < y < 1/2 (4 - 3 x)} *)
```

There are two ways to process these inequalities.  If the image is a polygon, as in this case, then we can get its convex hull.  If the region is bounded by curves, then we can use `Plot`.

**Convex Hull method**

```
vertices[ineqx_ && ineqy_] := 
  With[{ineq1 = List @@ ineqx, ineq2 = List @@ ineqy}, 
   Thread[{x, ineq2[[{1, -1}]]}] /. ({x -> #} & /@ #) &@ ineq1[[{1, -1}]]];

points = DeleteDuplicates @ Flatten[vertices /@ combinedPieces, 2]

(* {{-1, 1}, {0, 0}, {0, 2}, {5/7, -(5/7)}, {5/7, 13/14}, {1, -1}, {1, 1/2}, {2, -1}} *)

Needs["ComputationalGeometry`"];
Graphics[{
  EdgeForm[ColorData[1][1]], RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798], Opacity[0.2], 
  Polygon[points[[ComputationalGeometry`ConvexHull @ points]]]},
 Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Plot method**

```
Clear[rplot];
rplot[_[x1_, ___, x2_] && _[y1_, ___, y2_], opts : OptionsPattern[Plot]] := 
 Plot[{y1, y2}, {x, x1, x2}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, opts]

Show[
 rplot[#,
    PlotStyle -> ColorData[1][1], 
    FillingStyle -> 
     Directive[Opacity[1], Lighter[RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798], 0.8]]] & /@ 
  combinedPieces,
 PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> Automatic
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]