# Any ideas on how to use the Region` context?

Tags: version-9, undocumented

If you type

```
?Region`*
```

you'll get:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

which seems a bunch of interesting and not documented symbols.

Any idea (or experience) on how to use them?

**Edit**

By using our "collective spelunking" **I was able to work out [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39206/193)** - 
Great! :)

And Silvia used it [to write another one!](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39242/17)

Comment: ``Region`RegionMeasure[Circle[]]`` -> 2 Pi :)

Comment: @cormullion Great! I was trying with parametrized regions. So the objects involved should be Geometric thingies. Let's try!

Comment: ``Region`RegionCentroid[Rectangle[{5, 5}, {25, 25}]]`` gives `{15, 15}`

Comment: @cormullion ``Region`ConvexRegionQ[Circle[]]`` hey ``Region`ConvexRegionQ[Disk[]]``

Comment: Christmas has arrived in your region? :)

Comment: Check this:  ``Region`RegionProperty[Polygon[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {2, 3}}], {x, y}, "FastDescription"]``

Comment: @SimonWoods Hey! That's great! Is there an inverse function for that?

Comment: Also: How on earth did you arrive to `"FastDescription"`?

Comment: @belisarius, it's in the definition for ``Region`BoundedParametrization``

Comment: I thought I had checked out them all :(

Comment: Great find by the way. I wish we could get documentation for some of the useful stuff in these hidden-away packages.

Comment: In Simon's footsteps, trying to find valid arguments for **RegionProperty** I ran ``Union@Cases[
  ToExpression[#, InputForm, DownValues] & /@ Names["Region`*"], 
  HoldPattern[Region`RegionProperty[__, s_String]] :> s, Infinity]`` to find `{"Distance", "FastDescription", "ImplicitDescription", "Nearest",
"SpaceDimension"}`. **SpecialRegionProperty** can take `{"Assumptions", "BoundingBox", "Centroid", "ConvexQ", "Distance",
"ImplicitDescription", "InjectiveParametricDescription", "Instance",
"Measure", "Nearest", "ParametricDescription", "RegionDimension",
"SignedDistance", "SpaceDimension"}`

Comment: If you dare wade through all of it, do this: 1. force-load all symbols using ``Symbol/@Names["Region`*"]``  2. [Mass-spelunk](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15948/12) ``Scan[Spelunk, Names["Region`*"]]``

Comment: I think the usage of the ``"Region`"`` functions is different in V10 -- anyone around with an RPi to check?

Comment: @MichaelE2 There are [some more functions](http://i.stack.imgur.com/atQXE.png); `BallRegion`, `SimplexRegion` are changed to `Ball`, `Simplex`; at least `ParametricRegion` works different (don't know how yet).

Comment: @Silvia Try `ParametricRegion[{{x, y}, 0 < x < 1 && 0 < y < 2}, {x, y}]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 Hmm... Why they declare `{x, y}` twice :( And what about `RegionConvert` in Simon's answer?

Comment: @Silvia I don't know.

Comment: @Silvia `ParametricRegion[{{s, t}, -1 <= s <= 1 && -1 <= t <= 1, {s^2 t^2, s t^3}}]`

Comment: @belisarius Thanks! Looks interesting and subtle :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For a more clear view, here is a table of some of the `Region` functions.

```
AppendTo[$ContextPath, "Region`"]

Clear[testfunc]
testfunc[reg_] := {ToString /@ #, Through[#[reg]]} &[{
                    ConvexRegionQ,
                    BoundedRegionQ,
                    RegionDimension,
                    Module[{dim = RegionEmbeddingDimension[#]},
                           var = Symbol["x" <> ToString[#]] & /@ Range[dim];
                           dim] &,
                    RegionMeasure,
                    RegionCentroid,
                    RegionProperty[#, var, "FastDescription"] &,
                    RegionProperty[#, var, "ImplicitDescription"] &,
                    RegionElement,
                    LevelFunction[RegionProperty[#, var, "FastDescription"][[1, 2]]] &
                  }] // 
          Grid[Insert[#, {ConvexRegionQ, BoundedRegionQ, RegionDimension, 
               RegionEmbeddingDimension, RegionMeasure, RegionCentroid, 
               FastDescription, ImplicitDescription, RegionElement, 
               LevelFunction}, 2]\[Transpose], Dividers -> All, 
            FrameStyle -> GrayLevel[.8], Alignment -> Left] & // Quiet
```

In addition of BoxRegion, other `*Region`s also seems to be used to declare regions:

```
Names["Region`*Region"]
```

> {"BallRegion", "BooleanRegion", "BoxRegion", "EllipsoidRegion", "EmptyRegion", "FullRegion", "InverseTransformedRegion", "ParametricRegion", "SimplexRegion", "TransformedRegion"}

For example, a 2D triangle embeded in 7D space:

```
tri3d = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {3, 3}];
tri7d = ArrayFlatten[{{tri3d, ConstantArray[0, {3, 4}]}}];
(* a random rotate in 7D space: *)
rt7d = RotationTransform[{{0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, RandomInteger[{-1, 1}, 7]},
                         ConstantArray[0, 7]];
tri7d = rt7d /@ tri7d;
testfunc@SimplexRegion[tri7d]
```

[image: test for 7D triangle]

Maybe some of them (`LevelFunction`) work only on "full-rank" regions?

```
simplex = Function[dim, SimplexRegion[RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {dim + 1, dim}]]] @ 4
testfunc @ simplex
```

[image: test for simplex]

Some regions look like special cases:

```
RegionDimension@EmptyRegion[2]
```

> $-\infty$

```
RegionMeasure@FullRegion[3]
```

> $\infty$

### Edit:

**`SimplePolygonPartition`** can be used to divide self-intersecting `Polygon` to simple pieces. The usage is like

```
SimplePolygonPartition[Polygon[...]]
SimplePolygonPartition[Polygon[...],Graphics`Region`RegionDump`FillingMethod->"OddEvenRule"]
```

An example can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/41255/17).

Comment: Great! In a few days we'll be able to write a manual! :)

Comment: @belisarius *The Uncomplete Unofficial Documentation for Undocumented Functions* :P

Comment: take a look! http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39206/193

Comment: @belisarius Thanks for you and Simon's enlightenment, I found [a similar solution](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39242/17) :)

Comment: @belisarius Found a new one `SimplePolygonPartition` :)

Comment: Yup, I found it while trying to answer that very question, but I couldn't make it work but for very small polygs. I forgot to document it here, sorry. Upvoted your linked answer :)

Comment: @Silvia, `SimplePolygonPartition` has appeared on the site [before](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=SimplePolygonPartition)

Comment: @SimonWoods Great works! I'm having fun of [Tracing those functions](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CxTsk.png) :)

Comment: @Silvia, have fun :-)  I spend some time a while ago digging into ``Graphics`Mesh``, learning how to work with `MeshObject`s. I found some quite cool stuff but then got fed up when I upgraded to version 9 and a lot of it no longer worked the same way. One of the perils of using undocmented functions I suppose.

Answer (score 13):

This is quite a find. I've only had time to play with it a little, but are some interesting results:

```
Region`ConvexRegionQ[Disk[{1., 0.}]]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
Region`RegionCentroid[Disk[{1., 0.}]]
```

> ```
> {1., 0.}
> ```

```
Region`RegionMeasure[Disk[{1., 0.}]]
```

> ```
> π
> ```

```
Region`RegionIntersection[Disk[{0, 0}], Disk[{1, 0}]]
```

seems to do nothing, but

```
Region`RegionMeasure @ Region`RegionIntersection[Disk[{0, 0}], Disk[{1, 0}]]
```

> ```
> -(Sqrt[3]/2) + (2 π)/3
> ```

It appears one can create regions and operate on them:

```
box = Region`BoxRegion[{0, 0}, {2, 3}];
Region`RegionMeasure @ box
```

> ```
> 6
> ```

```
Region`RegionCentroid @ box
```

> {1, 3/2}

Comment: +1 And it seems most of them also work for 3D cases.

Answer (score 9):

Its interesting to note that the `Region` context is loaded when you evaluate `` Graphics`Region`RegionInit[] ``. Old favourite `` Graphics`Mesh `` gets loaded too. There is some interesting looking stuff in `` Graphics`Region ``, clearly incomplete, for example one of the definitions is this...

```
BoundingRegion[___] := "Implement me..."
```

I've not done much spelunking yet, but did find this:

```
Graphics`Region`RegionInit[];

RegionConvert[Disk[]]
(* MeshRegion[{2, 2}, {951, 2289, 1339}, <>] *)

Graphics[Line @ MeshCoordinates[%, 1]]
```

[image]

Comment: "Implement me..." There's some [sentient code](http://venturebeat.com/2013/11/29/sentient-code-an-inside-look-at-stephen-wolframs-utterly-new-insanely-ambitious-computational-paradigm)!

Answer (score 7):

Four more:

`RegionNearest[]` returns the nearest point inside a region to a given point:

```
AppendTo[$ContextPath, "Region`"]

RegionNearest[Disk[], {3, 4}]
(*
 {3/5, 4/5}
*)
```

`RegionDifference[]` seems to return unevaluated ... but no:

```
RegionMeasure@RegionDifference[Rectangle[], Disk[]]
(*
 1 - π/4
*)
```

`TransformedRegion[]` also seems to return unevaluated ... but again:

```
RegionMeasure@TransformedRegion[Rectangle[], ScalingTransform[{3, 2}]]
(*
 6
*)
```

`ParametricRegion[]`:

```
RegionMeasure@ParametricRegion[{{x, y}, 0 < x < 1 && 0 < y < 2}]
(*
 2
*)
```

Comment: @Silvia `RegionMeasure@ParametricRegion[{{x, y}, 0 < x < 1 && 0 < y < 2}]`

Comment: Sorry I missed that.. But `ParametricRegion` will be my most interested one :)

Comment: Wow! Brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

So far as I know, the region properties can be:

```
In[1]:= Union[
 Join[Region`SpecialBoundaryProperty[]; 
  Cases[GeneralUtilities`Definitions[
    "SpecialBoundariesDump`SRBdryRule"], _String, -1], 
  Region`SpecialRegionProperty[]; 
  Cases[GeneralUtilities`Definitions[
    "SpecialRegionsDump`SRPropRule"], _String, \[Infinity]]]]

Out[1]= {"Assumptions", "Boundary", "BoundingBox", "Centroid", \
"ConvexQ", "Distance", "ImplicitDescription", \
"InjectiveParametricDescription", "Instance", "LinearGraphics", \
"Measure", "Nearest", "ParametricDescription", "Primitive", "Region", \
"RegionDimension", "SignedDistance", "SimpleBoundary", \
"SimplicialDecomposition", "SpaceDimension", "Type"}
```

Unfortunately, this list is *incomplete*. According to

```
In[2]:= Region`RegionProperty[Pyramid[],{x,y,z},"FastDescription"]
Out[2]= {{{x,y,z},-4 (-2-2 y+2 z)>=0&&-4 (-2+2 x+2 z)>=0&&-4 (-2+2 y+2 z)>=0&&4 (2+2 x-2 z)>=0&&16 z>=0}}
In[3]:= Region`RegionProperty[Pyramid[],{x,y,z},"FastImplicitDescription"]
Out[3]= -4 (-2-2 y+2 z)>=0&&-4 (-2+2 x+2 z)>=0&&-4 (-2+2 y+2 z)>=0&&4 (2+2 x-2 z)>=0&&16 z>=0
In[4]:= Region`RegionProperty[Pyramid[],{x,y,z},True,"ImplicitDescription"]
Out[4]= {(x==-1&&((y==-1&&z==0)||(-1<y<0&&z==0)||(y==0&&z==0)||(0<y<1&&z==0)||(y==1&&z==0)))||(-1<x<0&&((y==-1&&z==0)||(-1<y<x&&0<=z<=1+y)||(y==x&&0<=z<=1+y)||(x<y<0&&0<=z<=1+x)||(y==0&&0<=z<=1+x)||(0<y<-x&&0<=z<=1+x)||(y==-x&&0<=z<=1+x)||(-x<y<1&&0<=z<=1-y)||(y==1&&z==0)))||(x==0&&((y==-1&&z==0)||(-1<y<0&&0<=z<=1+y)||(y==0&&0<=z<=1-y)||(0<y<1&&0<=z<=1-y)||(y==1&&z==0)))||(0<x<1&&((y==-1&&z==0)||(-1<y<-x&&0<=z<=1+y)||(y==-x&&0<=z<=1+y)||(-x<y<0&&0<=z<=1-x)||(y==0&&0<=z<=1-x)||(0<y<x&&0<=z<=1-x)||(y==x&&0<=z<=1-y)||(x<y<1&&0<=z<=1-y)||(y==1&&z==0)))||(x==1&&((y==-1&&z==0)||(-1<y<0&&z==0)||(y==0&&z==0)||(0<y<1&&z==0)||(y==1&&z==0))),True}
```

`"FastImplicitDescription"` is also a valid region property.
So, is there a **complete** list?