# Recognize simple shapes in an image and color them randomly?

Tags: graphics, image-processing, generative-art, image

I have an image of polygons built from a polar function (see below).  I'd like to color each triangle or quadrilateral a random color.

Firstly, I'm not sure how to separate the simple shapes.

Secondly,  I can't think of a simple way to color each a random color (only 3 different colors result with `Colorize`).

```
sunflower = 2 Pi (1 - 1/GoldenRatio);
PolarCoordinate[r_, theta_] := r {Cos[theta], Sin[theta]}
Graphics[Polygon[
   Table[PolarCoordinate[i^10, i*sunflower], {i, 1, 1000}]], 
  AspectRatio -> 1] // Colorize
```

[image]

Comment: A simple first approach could be `p = Graphics[
   Polygon[Table[PolarCoordinate[i^10, i*sunflower], {i, 1, 500}]], 
   ImageSize -> 1000];
MorphologicalComponents[ColorNegate@Dilation[p, 2], 
  CornerNeighbors -> False] // Colorize`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this (there's many ways to skin this cat) will do it. Play with parameters to your liking:

```
SelectComponents[MorphologicalComponents[yourImageHere, .8], "Area", 
  10^9] // Colorize
```

Putting this with the excellent linearization idea of *Pickett* in the comments, we can get this pleasing result:

```
sunflower = 2 Pi (1 - 1/GoldenRatio);
PolarCoordinate[r_, theta_] := r {Cos[theta], Sin[theta]}
p = Graphics[
   Line[Table[PolarCoordinate[i^10, i*sunflower], {i, 1, 1000}]], 
   AspectRatio -> 1];

SelectComponents[MorphologicalComponents[p, .89], "Area", 
  10^3] // Colorize
```

[image]

Comment: ...where `yourImageHere` is the OP's plot but where `Polygon` has been replaced by `Line`.

Comment: @Pickett: Good idea, cleans up result nicely!

Comment: Brilliant!  Is it possible to change the color palette (`ColorFunction`(?))?  Note that `Colorize[yourImageHere,ColorFunction->"Rainbow"]` ruins the stained glass randomness.

Comment: @user8454: Sure, you can just replace the `Colorize` above with something like `Colorize[#, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"] &`. You'll probably want to play around with parameters, and perhaps implement your own `ColorFunction` to get the results you want.

Comment: @rasher: Is there a way to avoid the colors with like neighbors in this, as well as using `ColorFunction->"Rainbow"`?

Comment: @user8454: Yes, but you'll need to either write a custom color function using the palette you want, or use rules either for coloring or from getting component measures (see the documentation re: morphological processing, many examples). Probably some elegant way to use `Rainbow` but randomized, but I'll leave it to the graphics experts (perhaps Mr.W or Belisaurius will chime in, they cut a mean graph...)

Comment: @rasher, it's probably easier to modify the component matrix than the color function. e.g. `Colorize[Mod[863 #, 231], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"] &`

Comment: @SimonWoods-- Excellent and thank you!  I don't actually understand how `Colorize` uses that matrix.  Do you see how `ColorFunction->"VisibleSpectrum"` could be implemented?  `ColorFunctionScaling->True` doesn't help for some reason...

Answer (score 8):

This method can be very time-consuming, and the scale of the original graphics seems need be small (thus `i^10/10^30`), but yes you can do it in vectorgraph way, with the help of `` Region` `` functions [described here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39184/17).

```
sunflower = 2 Pi (1 - 1/GoldenRatio);
PolarCoordinate[r_, theta_] := r {Cos[theta], Sin[theta]}
poly = Polygon[Table[PolarCoordinate[i^10/10^30, i*sunflower], {i, 900, 1000}]] // N;

Graphics`Region`RegionInit[];

simplePolySet = SimplePolygonPartition[poly];

Graphics[
         {EdgeForm[White], ColorData["DarkRainbow"][RandomReal[]], #} & /@ 
             simplePolySet (*uncomment to manipulate them:*)(* /.
                  Polygon[pts__] :>
                   GeometricTransformation[
                              Polygon[pts],
                              TranslationTransform[Norm[Mean[pts]]^5 Normalize[Mean[pts]]]
                                          ]*)
        ]
```

[image: sunflower]

Comment: Nicely done - I tried `SimplePolygonPartition` but gave up after it just sat there thinking for ten minutes.

Comment: @SimonWoods Thanks :) I guess when the scale is too large (here $10^{30}$), this function will stuck because of some inner parts (in fact, `IntersectQ`, who used something like ``Graphics`Mesh`Developer`CreateMesh ``) using machine number.