# Code for a color bucket fill (seed fill) of a bounded irregular area?

Tags: graphics, algorithm, generative-art

In images like the one shown here, I would like to be able to pick an x,y coordinate and fill the bounded interior with a specified color.  That functionality is well known in PhotoShop and GIMP, but I can't seem to find even a simple version of such code for Mathematica.  I'm not expecting a great GUI - just some code that I can use and modify.

[image]

```
For[i = 1, i <= 100, i++,
  t[i] = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {20, 2}]];

For[i = 1, i <= 100, i++,
 g[i] = Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[1], 
    BezierCurve[t[i], SplineClosed -> True, 
     SplineDegree -> RandomInteger[{4, 16}]]}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
   ImageSize -> {1000, 1000}]; Print[i];
 Print[g[i]]]
```

Comment: Is the input a `Graphics` or an `Image` object?

Comment: @kglr  Graphics. I added some code to the figure.  Watch out for the 100 iterations.

Comment: After getting the jaggies with Rasterize, I tried this and it works nicely: `labels = MorphologicalComponents[g[1]]
Colorize[labels] `

Comment: A related question: [(41118)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41118/17)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can remove border components from `MorphologicalComponents` using `DeleteBorderComponents` or `SelectComponents`, colorize and create a mesh object using `ImageMesh`:

```
imgMesh = ImageMesh @ Colorize @ DeleteBorderComponents @
 MorphologicalComponents @ Rasterize[#, ImageResolution -> 200] &
```

Using a random sample of size 9 from OP's `g /@ Range[100]`:

```
SeedRandom[1]
Multicolumn[Graphics[{RandomColor[], EdgeForm[Gray], #} & /@ 
     MeshPrimitives[imgMesh @ g @ #, 2], ImageSize -> 250] & /@ 
  RandomSample[Range[100], 9], 3]
```

[image]

We get the same picture using `imgMesh2` where

```
imgMesh2 = ImageMesh @ Colorize @
   SelectComponents[
      MorphologicalComponents @ Rasterize[#, ImageResolution -> 200], 
      #AdjacentBorderCount == 0 &] &;
```

Comment: Those are beautiful!  Thank you.