# Convert DelaunayTriangulation-> Graph->AdjacencyMatrix

Tags: matrix, graphs-and-networks, computational-geometry

Is there a way to convert a Delaunay triangulation into a `Graph` structure, so that one can generate an adjacency matrix of the triangulation?

Comment: You don't need to go through a graph.  Once you have the Delaunay triangulation as a set of point-index `pairs`, you can `SparseArray@Thread[pairs -> 1]` assuming the indices start from 1.

Comment: Bigger question: in what format do you have the Delaunay triangulation?

Comment: BTW you will [soon](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DelaunayMesh.html) be able to simply `DelaunayMesh[pts]["AdjacencyMatrix"]`.

Comment: @Szabolcs *soon* for what values of soon?

Comment: @Yves I don't know more than you.

Comment: Just as a follow-up from @Szabolcs remark: `DelaunayMesh[pts]["AdjacencyMatrix"]` worked up to V12.1, but is no longer supported in V12.2. It just produces meaningless errors.

Answer (score 6):

In version 10, which is at the moment publicly accessible through the Programming Cloud, you can simply use:

```
DelaunayMesh[points]["AdjacencyMatrix"]
```

to obtain an adjacency matrix.

---

[The IGraph/M package](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) has support for converting meshes into matrices. This problem would be solved by

```
mesh = DelaunayMesh[points]
IGMeshCellAdjacencyMatrix[mesh, 0]
```

`0` means the adjacency relation of 0-dimensional mesh cells, i.e. points.

---

There is also a function for directly constructing the Delaunay graph:

```
IGDelaunayGraph[points]
```

Answer (score 5):

Since you want to go from `DelaunayTriangulation` to `Graph` to `AdjacencyMatrix`, how about the following (**works in version 9.0.1**)

```
pts = RandomReal[4, {25, 2}];
```

Load the undocumented [Region](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39184/any-ideas-on-how-to-use-the-region-context?lq=1) context

```
Graphics`Region`RegionInit[];
```

Then,

```
mesh = DelaunayMesh[pts];

graph = Graph @ MeshTopologyGraph[mesh][[1]];

( matrix = AdjacencyMatrix[graph] ) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

OR

```
pairs = MeshTopologyGraph[mesh][[1]] /. Rule -> List

matrix = Normal @ SparseArray[Thread[pairs -> 1]]
```

Surprise , surprise as suggested by Szabolcs (only, you can do it now in v9) but with a little twist, you can get it directly:

```
matrix = mesh[[1]]["AdjacencyMatrix"]
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me on _v8_.. Picture [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/k1t2S.png).

Comment: @Öskå. Hmmm. I don't have v8, but good to know. It works fine in v9.0.1

Comment: @Öskå, does the `Region` context work for you in v8?

Comment: `DelaunayMesh` doesn't seem to work. [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qtDI3.png). Could you please set a `SeedRandom` and upload a picture of the `Graph` in the comments? :)

Comment: @Öskå [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Awv6M.png). `SeedRandom[2345]`

Comment: I am confused, it says this works for version 9, but for me `DelaunayMesh` is still in blue in version 9.0, in the documentation it says it was introduced in version 10.0.  Also for me, I can't use `MeshTopologyGraph` even after calling the `Init[]` function - I have to use `` Graphics`Region`MeshTopologyGraph ``,  and that function spits out a `GraphicsComplex` that isn't really suitable for `Graph`

Comment: @JasonB I don't know about version 9 but it works in 9.0.1 as I stated, I just tried it now.

Comment: For some reason it only works if I type out ``Graphics`Region`DelaunayMesh``

Answer (score 3):

These days, one would do something like the following:

```
pts = RandomReal[1, {18, 2}];
dm = DelaunayMesh[pts];
mcg = MeshConnectivityGraph[dm]
```

and then evaluate `AdjacencyMatrix[mcg]` if you want to see the corresponding adjacency matrix.