# Efficient way to get adjacency information from MeshRegion

Tags: regions, mesh

What is the most efficient way to get adjacency information from a `MeshRegion`, i.e. some efficient representation of which vertex is connected to which other one?

The result could be a packed adjacency list, a sparse array or a `Graph`.

Example:

```
r = TriangulateMesh@DiscretizeRegion[Cuboid[]]
```

Now `r["AdjacencyMatrix"]` does not work.  `MeshCells[r,1]` works well, but it gives a list of `Line`s, not a packed array.

```
adj1 = MeshCells[r, 1];

adj2 = Developer`ToPackedArray[adj1[[All, 1]]];

{ByteCount[adj1], ByteCount[adj2]}
(* {3433488, 312280} *)
```

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/51370/12

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use:

```
r["MakeRepresentation"["ElementMesh"]]["ElementConnectivity"]
```