# Generating uniform random points over a binary image

Tags: random, image, distributions, regions

So I recently read [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57938) excellent post about generating random points over arbitrary regions. I hope Wolfram eventually builds that functionality into *Mathematica*'s `Random` functions. I want to do this for binary images.

Given a binary image like this:

[image: Map of the UK]

... I can generate random lattice points over the black parts by doing:

```
 ListPlot[RandomSample[PixelValuePositions[Binarize[img], Black],1500],
  AspectRatio -> ImageAspectRatio[img]]
```

which gives this plot:

[image: Random lattice points]

However, the problem is that all generated random points will lie on integer coordinates. For example, the point `{150, 100}` can be generated by my approach, yet the point `{150.278, 100.123}` will never be generated. I want to generate random points uniformly *anywhere* within the coastlines/black regions.

Comment: Since the linked answer already provides a number of methods to generate points within a Region I believe this question would be answered by a way to convert your binary mask into a Region; is that correct?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard yes, that's one possibility unless there's another way. You'd need to be able to generate regions for all black parts of the image, including disconnected components however

Comment: You can think of a pixel as a randomly selected square "cell", then you can add a `RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 2]` on it.

Comment: @Silvia Let me see if I understand:  Generate positions for all black pixels; randomly pick one, then generate a `RandomReal` pair within that "cell"; do this as many times as points are needed.  Are you going to write that up as an answer?

Comment: @Silvia Well I'm going to post it.  If you would like to post your own implementation do so and I shall delete mine.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard By all means, please post your answer! I'm not able to post one right now because of some network issues...

Comment: @Silvia It's posted (and now Accepted) below.  Thanks for the brilliant idea!  I owe you a Bounty; let me know where you would like it applied.  (Either for an answer of your own or to draw attention to a question that matters to you.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Already read and voted :) About the bounty, actually I'm interested in [this question about treemap](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6357/17) very much! Thanks :D

Comment: @Silvia Any specific message you would like to attach to that bounty or shall I use the generic "This question has not received enough attention"?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks. I think the generic message will do fine. (I myself just want to see some fancy and general treemap generator, which is exactly covered by the original question.)

Comment: @Silvia Bounty started.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Update

[Silvia](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/17/silvia) proposed a much faster algorithm that I believe produces I uniform distribution.
Here is my implementation of it.

```
pointsInMask2[mask_Image, n_Integer, range : {_, _} : {0, 1/2}] :=
  Reverse @ ImageData @ Binarize[mask, range]\[Transpose] //
    SparseArray[#]["NonzeroPositions"] & //
      RandomChoice[#, n] + RandomReal[{-1, 0}, {n, 2}] &

img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoPNX.png"];

Graphics[{
  AbsolutePointSize[1], Opacity[0.3],
  pointsInMask2[img, 75000] // Point
}]
```

[image]

The optional range parameter specifies the range of values in the mask image that are valid target area.

```
Graphics[{
  AbsolutePointSize[1], Opacity[0.3],
  pointsInMask2[img, 75000, {1/2, 1}] // Point
}]
```

[image]

---

### A "brute force" method

Although my first method will be superior if one wishes to generate many points there is a more direct and simple approach, though it does not benefit from any of the optimizations in the linked question.  That is simply to generate random points and select the ones for which the matching [`ImageValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageValue.html) is closer to black than white.  This requires redundant sampling and will be increasingly slow on images with a small percentage of black pixels.  (For now I am simply estimating the number of samples needed and not performing a check to make sure the requested number are actually produced; if this method proves useful I shall refine my approach.)

```
pointsInMask[mask_Image, n_Integer] :=
  Module[{dims, pts, n2},
    dims = ImageDimensions[mask];
    n2 = ⌈ 1.1 n #/(# - ImageData[mask] ~Total~ 2) &[Times @@ dims] ⌉;
    pts = RandomReal[#, n2] & /@ dims // Transpose;
    Select[pts, ImageValue[mask, #] < 0.5 &, n]
  ]
```

Test:

```
mask = Binarize @ Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoPNX.png"]

pts = pointsInMask[mask, 5000];

Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[1], Point @ pts}]
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is the best approach, take the random lattice points and then fuzz them in a random direction. But this new method doesn't produce a uniform distribution. There are strange diagonal runs http://imgur.com/uUfyxYw if you look closely. I think you're meant to add + `RandomReal[{-1/2, 1/2}, {n, 2}]` or possibly `RandomReal[{-1,1},{n,2}]` not `RandomReal[{-1, 0}, n]`.

Comment: @Histograms Ah, right, that was stupid!

Comment: @Histograms I used `{-1, 0}` because I wanted the space to start from {0, 0} rather than {1, 1} to follow the scheme of `ImageValue`.

Comment: Probably unimportant given the update, but `Nearest` can be used to speed up the brute force method: E.g., fyi, `data = ImageData[mask, DataReversed -> True]; nf = Nearest[Tuples[Range /@ dims] -> Flatten[Transpose@data, 1]]; pts = RandomReal[#, n2] & /@ dims // Transpose; Take[Pick[pts, Flatten@nf[pts], 0], n]`.

Answer (score 13):

Following up on my comment and borrowing a method from [Vectorizing an image like "Trace Bitmap" in Inkscape](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11524/vectorizing-an-image-like-trace-bitmap-in-inkscape/11556#11556):

```
mask = Binarize @ Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoPNX.png"];

{row, col} = ImageDimensions[mask];

intf = ListInterpolation @ Reverse @ ImageData @ mask;

region = DiscretizeGraphics @ 
  RegionPlot[intf[c, r] < 1/2, {r, 1, row}, {c, 1, col},
    PlotPoints -> {row, col}, MaxRecursion -> 0]
```

[image]

You can then apply whichever of the methods from [How to generate random points in a region?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/57938/121) that you find appropriate, e.g.:

```
pts = randomFromRegion[region, 15000];

Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[1], Point @ pts}]
```

[image]

Comment: This result is exactly what I want. However, the line with `region = DiscretizeGraphics...` is painfully slow. I was hoping there would be a way to turn the binary image into a sparser triangulation on the interior (with a more refined mesh near the coastlines) as that would be faster to operate on (by using the DirichletDistribution approach).

Comment: @Histograms I added a second answer.  Rather than a lengthy region generation but very fast point generation it goes the other direction; a few points are very fast to generate but making many will be slow.

Answer (score 9):

In version 11, one can use `ImageMesh[]` in tandem with `RandomPoint[]`, like so:

```
imsh = ImageMesh[ColorNegate[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoPNX.png"]]];
Graphics[Point[RandomPoint[imsh, 5000]]]
```

[image: random points from binary image]