# Random points from an image using a BernoulliDistribution

Tags: random, distributions, image

I am a Mathematica newbie. I need to sample random points from an image which I have stored in a variable img as:

```
image=Import["ExampleData/ocelot.jpg"]    
img = ImageData[image]
```

Can you guys suggest how I can use a BernoulliDistribution to sample points from the image using Flatten, Map, RandomVariate, Partition and Image functions?

I know a similar problem was discussed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83436/generating-uniform-random-points-over-a-binary-image) but the solutions there are very convoluted and I am not able to follow them. 
Thanks a lot for the help and very sorry if this seems like a duplicate post but I have spent the whole evening banging my head over the link to the post above but am not able to reproduce the same with the above functions. Thanks again!

Comment: Can you upload `image.jpg` somewhere?

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Can you please clarify if you actually have a grayscale image, or a binary image? The new example you gave is grayscale, so sampling over that is not as clear-cut as the binary image case, which is already dealt with in the thread you linked to.

Comment: The image I need to work with is grayscale. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want to vary the Bernoulli parameter p depending on the pixel grayscale value. Darker areas of the image are more likely to generate a black pixel and lighter areas more likely to be white.

```
img = Import["ExampleData/ocelot.jpg"];
dat = ImageData[img];
result = Image[
  Map[RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[#]] &, dat, {2}]]
```

[image: random stippling effect]

The positions where a 1 appears are given by:

```
PixelValuePositions[result, 1]
```

The sum of many images averaged over time converges to the grayscale image in the limit.

```
img = Import["ExampleData/ocelot.jpg"];
dat = ImageData[img];
ListAnimate[
 ImageAdjust[Image[#]] & /@ 
  Accumulate[
   ParallelTable[
    Map[RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[#]] &, dat, {2}], {30}]]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: This is quite nice!