# How to efficiently upsample a greyscale image to generate a representative binary image

Tags: matrix, image-processing, sparse-arrays

I want to create binary images by upsampling a series of greyscale images (192 x 144 resolution) by a factor of 10 with the new pixel values being a pseudorandom distribution of 0's & 1's based on the original grey level value. The new resolution would be 1920 x 1440.

Here is a small example of a greyscale image:

`i = Image[{{0.16, 0.22, 0.32}, {0.73, 0.06, 0.13}, {0., 0.86, 0.18}}, ImageSize->100]`

[image]

The following function gives the desired result for such small images/arrays:

```
SeedRandom[123]
resize[dat_] :=
 Map[SparseArray[
  Partition[
   RandomSample[
    ConstantArray[0, IntegerPart[(1 - #)*100]]~Join~
     ConstantArray[1, IntegerPart[100 #]]
  ], 10]] &, dat, {2}]

  s = resize[ImageData@i];
  bin = ArrayFlatten[s];
  Image[bin, ImageSize -> 100]
```

[image]

However, when I try to uses it for a larger image `ArrayFlatten` gets upset...

```
SeedRandom[123]
bigi = Image@RandomReal[1, {50, 50}, WorkingPrecision -> 2]
```

[image]

```
ArrayFlatten[resize[ImageData@bigi]]
```

[image]

Obviously, I am stepping outside of `ArrayFlatten`'s defined parameters, but I am unable to decipher the meaning of the error message...

Why is this happening?

Is there a simpler way to achieve my desired result for larger greyscale images?

Comment: This is probably a rounding issue. After all, not all matrices in the result of `resize` have the same dimension.

Comment: Also, I think `SparseArray` should be avoided here because the resulting arrays are not at all sparse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method is short, but slow at higher resolutions:

```
ImageApply[RandomVariate@*BernoulliDistribution, ImageResize[img, {100, 100}]]
```

Instead, it makes more sense to pre-generate a random image first which is much faster at high resolutions:

```
With[{dims = {1920, 1440}}, 
 Binarize[ImageSubtract[ImageResize[img, dims], RandomImage[1, dims]],0]]
```

See also [my answer here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/221994/72682).

Comment: Fascinating! While the original pixel shapes are obliterated, the overall binary distributions appear to be spatially similar.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe using `RandomChoice` works better (it does so for me).

```
f[img_, k_] := Image[ArrayFlatten[
    Map[
     RandomChoice[{1 - #, #} -> {0, 1}, {k, k}] &,
     ImageData[img],
     {2}
     ]
    ]];
```

Example:

```
f[ExampleData[{"Texture", "Bark"}], 5]
```

Comment: This works, although the cell tally's have a probabilistic weight rather than an exact representation of the grey-value. I'm still curious as to why this would be easier for `ArrayFlatten` to handle for large images than shuffling two `ConstantArray`'s and partitioning. Is it a packed-/unpacked-array issue?